# Any Observer or plugin event for specific module disable?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, event-observer, extensions, plugin

I want to perform some action when my custom module gets disable.  Is there any observer event or plugin event that being fired when i disable my module?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: in my opinion you can't use observers or plugins because magento core doesn't load. The "setup" part works with own logic without support of interceptors.

Comment: I think we can use plugin because controller's execute method is public. So i think we can implement with controller but not sure how to implement when we disable mymodule.

Comment: What controller do you mean? Your extension may be disabled from CLI. You can try add plugin to Magento\Setup\Console\Command\ModuleDisableCommand::run() but it useless...

Comment: Looking for the something. Any help will be great..

Comment: Can you please add the answer if you get solution of this thing ?

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you can create the Recurring script and use `Magento\Framework\Module\Manager` to check your module.

All recurring scripts executing are during each launch of the setup:upgrade command. Or you can use any other event to make changes.

Code will be something like this:

```
// Initialize module manager
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
    ....
) {
    ...
    $this->moduleManager = $moduleManager;
    ...
}
```

And then check if modules enabled:

```
if ($this->moduleManager->isEnabled('Vendor_Module')) {
    //the module is enabled
} else {
    //the module is disabled
}
```

Comment: where do i put that code?  i know how to check module is enable or not. I need even. when you disable or enable from command line it fire specific action.